# Cplex solver none applicable

Tags: cplex

I want to use cplex to solve a Mixed integer linear programming model for multi-
commodity multi-depot inventory routing problem.
When I finished all the programs, it was found that Solver not applicable (cplex).

I have tried to search for problems in my constraints but I cant find any. What should I do?

Here are my model:

```
int numProd=...;
int numWarehouse=...;
int numVehicle=...;
int numManufacturer=...;
int numDN=...;
int numPN=...;
int numPeriod=...;
int numFrom=...;
int numTo=...;
int numN=...;
int h=...;
int numXi=...;
int EN=...;//End Node
int numzero=...;
range N=1..numN;
range Prod=1..numProd;
range Vehicle=1..numVehicle;
range Manufacturer=1..numManufacturer;
range Warehouse=1..numWarehouse;
range Period=1..numPeriod;
range PN=1..numPN;
range DN=1..numDN;
range From=1..numFrom;
range To=1..numTo;
range rangeXi=1..numXi;


 int D[Prod][Warehouse][Period]=...;
 int C[PN][DN]=...;
 int CM[Prod][Manufacturer]=...;
 int FC[Vehicle]=...;
 int MINI[Prod][Manufacturer]=...;
 int PI[Prod][Warehouse]=...;
 int Tmax=...;
 int VC[Vehicle]=...;
 int M=1000000000;
 int Xi[rangeXi]=...;
 int T[rangeXi][rangeXi]=...;
dvar int QM[Prod][Manufacturer][Period];
dvar int QT[Prod][Manufacturer][Warehouse][Period];
dvar int I[Prod][Warehouse][Period];
dvar int UI[PN][Vehicle][Period];
dvar int W[PN][Vehicle][Period];
dvar int A[PN][Vehicle][Period];
dvar int U[i in DN][Vehicle][Period];
dvar boolean X[PN][DN][Vehicle][Period];
dvar boolean alpha[PN][Vehicle][Period];
dvar boolean beta[PN][Vehicle][Period];
dvar boolean phi[Vehicle][Period];


minimize (sum(t in Period, w in Warehouse, p in Prod) PI[p][w]*I[p][w][t]+ sum(v in Vehicle, t in Period, i in From, j in To) C[i][j]*X[i][j][v][t]+ sum(v in Vehicle, t in Period, i in From, j in To)FC[v]*phi[v][t]); //add
subject to 
{
  //Constraint 1
  forall (p in Prod, m in Manufacturer, t in Period){QM[p][m][t]<=CM[p][m];} 
   //Constraint 2
  forall(p in Prod, m in Manufacturer, t in Period, w in Warehouse){QM[p][m][t]==sum(p in Prod, m in Manufacturer, t in Period, w in Warehouse)QT[p][m][w][t];}
   //Constraint 3
  forall(p in Prod, m in Manufacturer, t in Period, w in Warehouse){QT[p][m][w][t]+I[p][w][t-1]==D[p][w][t]+I[p][w][t];}
   //Constraint 4
  forall(p in Prod, t in Period, w in Warehouse){I[p][w][0]==0;}
   //Constraint 5
   forall(p in Prod, t in Period, w in Warehouse){I[p][w][Tmax]==0;}
   //Constraint 6
   forall(p in Prod, t in Period, w in Warehouse){I[p][w][t]>=MINI[p][w];}
   //Constraint 8
   forall(h in PN, v in Vehicle, t in Period){sum(i in DN: i!=h )X[i][h][v][t]+sum(i in PN: i!=h )X[i][h][v][t]==0;}
     forall(h in DN, v in Vehicle, t in Period){sum(i in PN: i!=h )X[i][h][v][t]-sum(j in DN: j!=h )X[j][h][v][t]==0;}
   // Constraint 9
   forall(h in DN, v in Vehicle, t in Period){sum(i in PN: i!=h)X[i][h][v][t]+sum(i in DN: i!=h)X[i][h][v][t]
   -sum(j in DN: j!=h)X[h][j][v][t]-sum(j in N: j!=h)X[h][j][v][t]==0;}
   //Constraint 10
   forall(i in PN, v in Vehicle, t in Period){sum(b in PN: b!=i)X[i][b][v][t]+sum(i in DN: i!=h)X[i][h][v][t]
   -sum(j in DN: j!=h)X[h][j][v][t]-sum(j in N: j!=h)X[h][j][v][t]==0;}
    //Constraint 11
    forall(i in PN, v in Vehicle, t in Period){U[i][v][t]<=M*alpha[i][v][t];}
    //Constraint 12
    forall(v in Vehicle, t in Period){sum(i in PN)U[i][v][t]<=VC[v]*phi[v][t];}
    //Constraint 13
    forall(i in PN, t in Period){sum(v in Vehicle)U[i][v][t]==sum(p in Prod,w in Warehouse, m in Manufacturer, v in Vehicle)QT[p][m][v][t];}
    //Constrain 14
    forall(i in DN, v in Vehicle, t in Period){sum(b in DN:b!=i)X[i][b][v][t]+sum(b in PN:b!=i)X[i][b][v][t]==sum(b in DN:b!=i)X[b][i][v][t]+sum(b in DN:b!=i)X[b][i][v][t]==beta[i][v][t];}
    //Constraint 15
    forall(i in DN, v in Vehicle, t in Period){W[i][v][t]<=M*beta[i][v][t];}
    //Constraint 16
    forall(i in DN, t in Period,p in Prod,w in Warehouse){sum(v in Vehicle)W[i][v][t]==D[p][w][t]-I[p][w][t-1]+I[p][w][t];}
    //Constraint 17
    forall(v in Vehicle, t in Period){sum(j in DN)W[j][v][t]==sum(i in PN)U[i][v][t];}
    //Constraint 18
    forall(i in Prod,v in Vehicle, t in Period){sum(miu in DN)W[miu][v][t]==sum(theta in PN)U[theta][v][t];}
    //Constraint 19
    forall(v in Vehicle, t in Period){A[0][v][t]==0;}
    //Constraint 20
    forall(v in Vehicle, t in Period,i,j in rangeXi){A[i][v][t]+Tmax+ T[i][j]==0;}
    //Constraint 21
    forall(i in DN,v in Vehicle,t in Period){A[i][v][t]<=M*beta[i][v][t];}
    //Constraint 22
    forall(i in PN,v in Vehicle,t in Period){A[i][v][t]<=M*alpha[i][v][t];}
    //Constraint 23
    forall(v in Vehicle,t in Period){A[EN][v][t] <= Tmax;}
    //Constraint 24a
    forall(i in PN, v in Vehicle,t in Period){A[i][v][t]>=0;}
    //Constraint 24b
    forall(i in DN, v in Vehicle,t in Period){A[i][v][t]>=0;}
    //Constraint 24c
    forall(v in Vehicle,t in Period){A[0][v][t]>=0;}
 }   
 //End
```

my data:

```
//Notations & Indices
numManufacturer= 1;
numPeriod= 3;
numWarehouse= 3;
numProd= 1;
numVehicle= 2;
numPN= 1;
numDN= 4;
numN= 5;



SheetConnection my_data("inventory.xlsx");

D from SheetRead(my_data,"Sheet5'!B4:D6");
CM from SheetRead(my_data,"'Sheet5'!B15:D17");
FC from SheetRead(my_data,"'Sheet5'!A31:B31");
C from SheetRead(my_data,"'Sheet4'!B14:E17");
MINI from SheetRead(my_data,"'Sheet5'!B4:D6");
PI from SheetRead(my_data,"'Sheet5'!B23:B25");
numTmax= 35;
numVC= 150;
t from SheetRead(my_data,"'Sheet4'!B25:E28")


QM to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B4:D4");
QT to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B11:D11");
I to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B18:D18");
U to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B24:B25");
W to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B30:D31");
A to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B35:P36");
X to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B42:P43");
alpha to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B49:P50");
beta to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B56:P57");
phi to SheetwWrite(my_data,"'Sheet3'!B62:P63");
```

Link to the excel file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mt5o_oobPe4_PTY1YhWh7eK0qIVe5Tff/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110689523853740952011&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Can you copy Paste your Model and data so that Other Users could try ?

Comment: I've included my model as well as data

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in your model

```
int D[Prod][Warehouse][Period]=...;
```

which is a 3D array but then in your dat file

```
D from SheetRead(my_data,"Sheet5'!B4:D6");
```

Which is not good since SheetRead does not work with 3Darray

Since you seem to have only 1 product you could in the .mod write

```
int Dbis[Warehouse][Period]=...;
int D[i in 1..1][w in Warehouse][p in Period]=Dbis[w][p];
```

and in the .dat

```
Dbis from SheetRead(my_data,"'Sheet5'!B4:D6");
```